# Checking if dir exist if not make it

Tags: bash

This is what I have now

```
#!/bin/bash

# This would match files that begin with YYYYMMDD format.
files=([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*)

# If you want to match those in the current year, start it with that year instead.
# current_year=$(date +%Y)
# files=("$current_year"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*)

#expands its values to multiple arguments "${files[@]}"
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
 file_year=${file:0:4}

#  Adding -p option to mkdir would create the directory only if it doesn't exist.
  mkdir -p "$file_year"  

  file_month=${file:4:2}
  mkdir -p "$file_month”
  mv "$files" "$file_year"/"$file_month"

done
```

Getting errors
Line 19: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
line 22: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: It is a matter of spaces: define vars with `val=$(command)`. Spaces will break it. Also, `if [ condition ];`, spaces are needed.

Comment: I am brand new what do you mean by vars and val? Can you copy my code where you mean spaces? I am use to programming C and java

Comment: @user2776153 Please provide an example list of those filenames of files that matches your requirement.

Comment: The files are like I said it would be 20130513.c or 20120501 or 20130706 ...I am just trying to make directory by year ex. 2013 or 2012 etc. then mv those files into the dirs

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concept script for your requirement. I hope it helps.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This would match files that begin with YYYYMMDD format.
files=([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*)

# If you want to match those in the current year, start it with that year instead.
# current_year=$(date +%Y)
# files=("$current_year"[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*)

for file in "${files[@]}"; do
    file_year=${file:0:4}

    # You could just simply do this. Adding -p option to mkdir would create the directory only if it doesn't exist.
    # mkdir -p "$file_year"  

    if [[ -d $file_year ]]; then
        echo "Directory exists."
    else
        echo "Creating directory ${file_year}."
        mkdir "$file_year" || {
            # If it fails, send a message to user and break the loop.
            echo "Failed to create directory ${file_year}."
            break
        }
    fi

    # After creating the directory perhaps you want to move the file to it so:
    # mv "$file" "$file_year"
done
```

Comment: I understand hat your doing here just how does this work just this part files=([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*)  ... because later i want to then make dir by month inside the yr would i add  after the last fi statement into another if statement but itll be checking to see if months will be created inside that year dir if not make it and etc?

Comment: @Ryan It's a glob pattern just like *.*. Also, it stores the matches to an array. On later time you could use arrays to manipulate the values in it as you require. It was actually the same as having `for file in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*; do` but this time you only store it in an array first.

Comment: Got ya. last thing I think lol sorry like i said this is my forst scrpit but what is "${files[@]}"

Comment: @Ryan It expands its values to multiple arguments as if you called it with `"${files[0]}" "${files[1]}" "${files[2]}"` and so on..

Comment: in java the for call is a for loop is that the same in this case?  "for file in"

Comment: I'm not sure about the for loop in java sorry. Bash somehow treats its loops differently and java is more pointer oriented so I suggest seeing them as just what they are somehow, and not really compare.

Comment: is there a loop that checks all files in the code you just wrote and puts in the array or am I going to write that part?

Comment: @Ryan Array assignments are true A=(values) where values are separated by spaces and grouped by quoting. If you mean checks al files as generates files with proper filename format, `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*` does that and expands to multiple values so the array `files` would have those values. All matches are file that begin in date format (`YYYYMMDD`). If you want to check other properties of those files you can do it on the `for` loop.

Comment: no I want it to run through all the files and make the dir the year which you wrote. Just asking if I ran this code you it check all files or the frst one and stop

Comment: @Ryan It would go through all the files.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for putting up with me ... like I said its my first script just use to using java ...

Comment: Im going to edit my post to add months I just want you to let me know if it wrong and why but can you walk me though I mean I deff picked up on what you thrown down now I guess is just how to do cd in script .. I bought a script basic book :) lol

Comment: @Ryan Your file_month declaration should be `file_month=${file:4:2}`. There are also many other parameter expansion options you could use too. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

Comment: why is it 4:2 not 4:6 I thought it went 012345 etc in the array and you would wanna grab the next 2 after yr?...........NM i got it you start at 4 and grab the next 2 .... blonde moment

Comment: when I run my script in my test area it makes 2 directories one is 2013 or 2012 then it also makes "2012 and "2013 I am guessing i have an extra one of "

Comment: It's one of your commands: `“$file_year/$file_month”`. It's not really using an ASCII double quote like `"`.

Comment: so I can get rid of them or add single quotes?

Comment: No just use the normal double quotes: `"$file_year/$file_month"`. What you used was `“`.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```
mkdir -p "$file_month”
```

that last character is not a double quote `"`. It's a "RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK", `”` `U+201D`.

`"` vs. `”`

If you get an error message about mismatched quotation marks, the best way to track it down is to search for the `"` in your editor, making sure you have an even number on each line.